# How to disable daily upgrade and clean on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I just updated to Ubuntu 16.04 and have been facing outages that I've traced to running unattended upgrades (which incidentally shutdown the tomcat server).

I would like to disable all unattended upgrades so I can run them manually when the server is not in a mission-critical state.

I see this line in /var/log/syslog

```
Jun  1 06:27:23 www3 systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
```

How do I prevent this process from running?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At first I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove unattended-upgrades
```

But it was insufficient.  I also had to do this:

```
sudo systemctl stop apt-daily.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 11):

Just a supplementary, first you can list the task:

```
sudo systemctl list-timers
```

and find apt-daily-upgrade.timer, then disable it

```
sudo systemctl stop apt-daily-upgrade.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.timer
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 4):

Like [vaclav.blazek](https://superuser.com/users/1002907/vaclav-blazek)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1616909/166158), but instead of remove it, you can modify it.

Based on [this documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades), you can change option that available in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`.

```
// Do "apt-get update" automatically every n-days
// (0=disable, 1=1 day, 7= 1 week)
// Check new update.
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";

// Do "apt-get upgrade --download-only" every n-days
// (0=disable, 1=1 day, 7= 1 week)
// Download new update.
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0"

// Do "apt-get autoclean" every n-days
// (0=disable, 1=1 day, 7= 1 week)
// Clean old updates.
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";

// Run the "unattended-upgrade" security upgrade script
// every n-days 
// (0=disable, 1=1 day, 7= 1 week)
// Requires the package "unattended-upgrades" and will write
// a log in /var/log/unattended-upgrades
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

So, if the scenario you want is to notify-only on daily update, it will looks like:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

So, if the scenario you want is to download without upgrade on daily upgrade, it will looks like:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

Or, if you want to do it all manually a.k.a disable it, it will looks like:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "0";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

Basically, just zero it all.

There are two files that contain the configuration, namely:

- `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`; and
- `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`

So, check both files to make sure the configurations is as you need.

I hope this will you you.

Answer (score 3):

This question references Ubuntu 16.04 but this answer is also valid for all subsequent releases so far (18.04 and 20.04) and probably Debian as well.

In `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` directory, find a file that contains line

```
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

(in my case it is `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`)
and comment the line out or remove it completely.

If you want to disable automatic package list udpate as well then comment out/remove following line:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one. It only disables upgrades, while keeping other apt maintanance chores, like autoremove and autoclean, intact.

Answer (score 2):

I simply removed package unattended-upgrades.